# What's a really good book to get deep into sound design??

Tags: music, sound-design, cinema, mastering

I'm looking for a book that can help me understand every detail on how to make sounds from scratch and not just manipulate presets. I've been producing music for the past 2 years and i've created some really nice pieces, but it just feels impossible to get the extremely dark and massive cinema sounds i want. Thank you! :) This is a really nice community btw.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start with Andy Farnell's Designing Sound.

http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/designing-sound

Comment: + a MSc in mathematics/physics.

Comment: @Iain @oinkaudio @Dave Thank you so much for answering my question. I'll make sure to check these books out :) You've been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sources you can look into but not all of them are accurate. David Sonnenschien is great for explaining how to set up projects, how to analyze your script, how to create transitions, evoke the emotional energy of a a sonic landscape etc. Other good books or websites are:

The Foley Grail
www.epicsound.com
www.soundworkscollection.com

They are very good at explaining how to make sounds, share ideas and watch how the pro's do it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the David Sonnenschein book, but it's on my list.

Depending on what you planning on doing, Ric Viers The Sound Effects Bible is a 100% must. It's an easy read and really more of a reference book. Incredible though. Changed me after I got through it, I approached everything differently.

The second if you want to do a lot of field stuff is Ric's Location Sound Bible. There is definitely a lot of overlap with the two books, but when you do the SFX bible, you'll be able to cruise through the first few chapters of LSB.

I've heard that Paul Vrostek's Field Recording Manual is also very good.